# export vars for python setup.py install --prefix

Tags: python, installation, prefix, setup.py

When I install a python package with `prefix`

```
python setup.py install --prefix=$HOME/opt
```

In `~/.bashrc`, I modify the `PATH` environment var.

```
export PATH=$HOME/opt:$PATH
```

Are there any other environment variables that I need to modify?

Comment: I need modify other environment variables ?

Comment: You probably want to put $HOME/opt/bin in the PATH, not just the prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to modify PYTHONPATH.

Comment: thanks, now work, with `export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Answer (score 2):

Use virtualenv for this. Virtualenv creates a directory which acts as a "little unix". You can activate and deactivate this environment as you like, and keep multiple environments for different purposes. Activating the environment will take care of all the environment variables.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

```
virtualenv mynix
source mynix/bin/activate
cd packages/foo
python setup.py install
```