# scipy and numpy install on linux without root

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to install `scipy` and `numpy`. Because I don't have root privileges, when I tried to install `numpy` first, I typed `python setup.py install --prefix=/data3/home` which worked. When I then tried to install `scipy` it reported this error:

```
File "setup.py", line 230, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 218, in setup_package
    from numpy.distutils.core import setup
ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: tried this? [export vars for python setup.py install prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346869/export-vars-for-python-setup-py-install-prefix) Its definately a PYTHONPATH issue

Comment: can you give some more details commands?

Comment: After use your command,this issue has been fixed.And now it reported that:

Comment: Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.

Answer (score 6):

A more standard way around is to make a per-user install like described in [PEP 370](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/) :

```
pip install numpy --user
```

Or use a [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html).

Comment: I don't know what that is but it solved my problem lol why did you add --user?

Answer (score 2):

`export PYTHONPATH="/data3/home/:$PYTHONPATH"` should solve your problem.

What this does is that it appends your custom path `/data3/home` to the standard `PYTHONPATH` variable; all Python scripts will first check `/data3/home` for libraries (and hopefully find the one you need) before checking the system-wide directories (usually under `/usr/lib/python*`).